# Adding Select option with jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to adjust the option value according to the quantity of the product, for the combination selected. I have done as below:

```
 var html='';
 jQuery.each(array, function(i,val){
      html +='<option value="'+val+'">'+val+'</option>';
 });
 var select_div='<select id="ajaxselect"  name="product_qty">'+html+'</select>';
 // alert(old_price);
 $('#select_quantity').html(select_div);
 $("#ajaxselect").css({
      width: "50px", height: "50px", display: "block", top: "0px", left: "0px",
 });
```

Where array is defined and its value is coming.

This will give me this in view after jquery effect

```
 <div id="select_quantity">
      <select id="ajaxselect" name="product_qty" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4</option>
           <option value="5">5</option>
           <option value="6">6</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

But after selecting and subbmitting form, the product_quantity is not submitted as post element
The post is as below

```
 Array ( 
      [id] => 2 
      [name] => Cardigan Stitch 
      [img] => /images/product/174febdfab0e13f983cc3cce91c1a5b9.jpg 
      [pc_id] => 1 
      [price] => 15 
      [product_color] => 2 
      [product_size] => 4 
      [add_to_cart] => )
```

while it should be like this:

```
 Array ( 
      [id] => 2 
      [name] => Cardigan Stitch 
      [img] => /images/product/174febdfab0e13f983cc3cce91c1a5b9.jpg 
      [pc_id] => 1 
      [price] => 15 
      [product_color] => 2 
      [product_size] => 4 
      [product_qty] => 1 
      [add_to_cart] => )
```

I have done same in another project and its working fine there. But its not working here. CAn anyone please help me. Trying to fix it since 3 hours. Any kind of help are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please give Array instead of array.

Comment: Are you sure div `#select_quantity` is inside you `form` tag ?

Comment: @GGO well i have placed it inside form tag but after jquery effect form is closing above it. Yet the submit button is working and other elements are also submitted which are below the closing tag. But product_qty is not submitted.

Comment: Can you show us complete `form` html output please ? html before POST sending and after jquery effect

Comment: @GGO Thank you for your help. I solved it with your hint. I was opening the form after one div and closing the form in another div. The issue was with div. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SuzAannshrestha Great ! i posted answer, feel free to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your div `#select_quantity` is inside the submitted `form` tag. Maybe you have a misplaced closing tag in source code.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the selected value using :selected. Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  var html='';
            jQuery.each(Array, function(i,val){
            html +='<option value="'+val+'">'+val+'</option>';
            });
            var select_div='<select id="ajaxselect" name="product_qty">'+html+'</select>';
            $('#select_quantity').html(select_div);
            alert($( "#select_quantity option:selected").text())
            
            $("#ajaxselect").css({
            width: "50px", height: "50px", display: "block", top: "0px", left: "0px",
            });


});
</script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```